# Smarty Sesssion Variable Problem

Tags: php, smarty

I have four files.

```
1. index.php
2. index.tpl
3. file2.php
4. file2.tp
```

I am setting a session variable in index.php like this

```
$_SESSION['isVisible'] = true;
```

Then I am accessing this variable in file2.php like this

```
echo ($_SESSION['isVisible']);
```

but it doesn't work.

I am not starting session manually because I think session is already started by Smarty.

Any idea how can I access this variable?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little snippet to help you detecting if a session has been started or not,

Don't forget as well that a session initialized with session_start will only be available to pages within the directory tree of the page that first created it.

It could explain why Smarty uses another session_id than your current script...

```
function session_is_started() {
    if (isset($_SESSION)) { 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        return false; 
    }
}

if (!session_is_started()){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['isVisible'] = true;
}

echo $_SESSION['isVisible'];
```

Comment: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open() failed: No such file or directory (2) in index.php on line 17

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at index.php:17) in index.php on line 17

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at index.php:17) in index.php on line 17

Comment: @Zahid Show us index.php around line 17 and the file where you are starting the session. You need to run the session_start code before line 17 in index.php but without seeing the files I don't know where you should put it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to use isset($_SESSION) when checking for the session instead of creating a function for this?